# fastlane scan for multiple simulator

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-scan

When I run Fastlane scan for one simulator device in devices it shows the number of test and failures properly. But when I add extra device in devices of Scanfile. Then number of test show 0.
Adding screenshot for the same.

[image: When number of devices more than 1]

Scanfile:

clean(true)
skip_build(true)
devices ["iPhone 11","iPhone 11 Pro"]

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: same issue here...

Answer (score 0):

After some research seems to be an xcpretty issue
https://github.com/xcpretty/xcpretty/issues/295

So the test are run but the output number is wrong. No fixes to this date. The solution other people are pointing is to switch that library for this one https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/XCTestHTMLReport